# How to properly install Open edX e-commerce service?

Tags: python, django, web, openedx

I am trying to install the e-commerce service on my Ubuntu 14.04 server, where OpenEDX is already running.
I am stuck there.  I cloned this project (https://github.com/edx/ecommerce) into /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform and ran the command "make requirements" in that folder. But then it crashed after 25 minutes. there were like 4-5 WARNINGS

```
npm install
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to ...
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing..
...
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.15
 GitHub
edx/ecommerce
ecommerce - Django application used to manage edX's product catalog and handle orders for those products.
```

I'm totally stuck there and don't even know much about configuring this platform.. as the documentation (http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/ecommerce/install_ecommerce.html#switch-from-shoppingcart-to-e-commerce) states i have to run a virtual envirnoment, so i tried the following out of the bitnami documentation:

activate the virtual environment (venv)

```
source /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/bin/
```

Cloning GitHub Repo and executing "make requirements"

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/edx
sudo git clone https://github.com/edx/ecommerce
cd ecommerce
sudo make requirements
```

now it shows me

```
    (venv)user@OpenEdxDev:/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/ecommerce$ sudo make requirements
npm install
npm WARN package.json edx-ecommerce@ No license field.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS iss                                                                          ue
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/adv                                                                          isories/130
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.15
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS iss                                                                          ue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issu                                                                          e
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. P                                                                          lease update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
/
> geckodriver@1.2.0 postinstall /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/ecommerce/node_modules/geckodriver
> node index.js

Complete.g... /kodriver... -
|
> phantomjs@1.9.20 install /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/ecommerce/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Downloading https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v1.9.19/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar                                                                          .bz2
Saving to /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/ecommerce/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.ta                                                                          r.bz2
Receiving...
  [================------------------------] 39%
Received 12854K total.
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/ecommerce/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/ecommerce/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-                                                                          linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1481636967989/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 -> /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/ecommerce                                                                          /node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/ecommerce/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin                                                                          /phantomjs
karma-sinon@1.0.5 node_modules/karma-sinon

karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.7 node_modules/karma-firefox-launcher

karma-requirejs@0.2.6 node_modules/karma-requirejs

karma-jasmine@0.3.8 node_modules/karma-jasmine

requirejs@2.3.2 node_modules/requirejs

karma-spec-reporter@0.0.20 node_modules/karma-spec-reporter
└── colors@0.6.2

jasmine-core@2.5.2 node_modules/jasmine-core

sinon@1.17.6 node_modules/sinon
├── formatio@1.1.1
├── samsam@1.1.2
├── lolex@1.3.2
└── util@0.10.3 (inherits@2.0.1)

gulp@3.9.1 node_modules/gulp
├── interpret@1.0.1
├── pretty-hrtime@1.0.3
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── tildify@1.2.0 (os-homedir@1.0.2)
├── minimist@1.2.0
├── v8flags@2.0.11 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── semver@4.3.6
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@2.2.1, supports-color@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1, ha                                                                          s-ansi@2.0.0)
├── orchestrator@0.3.8 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.14 (strip-bom@1.0.0, defaults@1.0.3, vinyl@0.4.6, graceful-fs@3.0.11, through2@0.6.5, mkd                                                                          irp@0.5.1, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
├── liftoff@2.3.0 (lodash.isstring@4.0.1, lodash.isplainobject@4.0.6, lodash.mapvalues@4.6.0, rechoir@0.6.                                                                          2, extend@3.0.0, flagged-respawn@0.3.2, resolve@1.1.7, fined@1.0.2, findup-sync@0.4.3)
└── gulp-util@3.0.7 (array-differ@1.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.3, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0,                                                                           lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, beeper@1.1.1, replace-ext@0.0.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, f                                                                          ancy-log@1.2.0, vinyl@0.5.3, lodash.template@3.6.2, gulplog@1.0.0, through2@2.0.3, multipipe@0.1.2, datefo                                                                          rmat@1.0.12)

karma-coverage@0.4.2 node_modules/karma-coverage
├── minimatch@2.0.10 (brace-expansion@1.1.6)
├── source-map@0.4.4 (amdefine@1.0.1)
├── dateformat@1.0.12 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.7.0)
└── istanbul@0.3.22 (abbrev@1.0.9, async@1.5.2, wordwrap@1.0.0, nopt@3.0.6, esprima@2.5.0, once@1.4.0, sup                                                                          ports-color@3.1.2, which@1.2.12, mkdirp@0.5.1, fileset@0.2.1, resolve@1.1.7, escodegen@1.7.1, js-yaml@3.7.                                                                          0, handlebars@4.0.6)

gulp-jshint@1.12.0 node_modules/gulp-jshint
├── minimatch@2.0.10 (brace-expansion@1.1.6)
├── through2@0.6.5 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@1.0.34)
├── rcloader@0.1.2 (lodash@2.4.2, rcfinder@0.1.9)
├── gulp-util@3.0.7 (array-differ@1.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.3, beeper@1.1.1, lodash._rees                                                                          cape@3.0.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, f                                                                          ancy-log@1.2.0, minimist@1.2.0, vinyl@0.5.3, lodash.template@3.6.2, chalk@1.1.3, gulplog@1.0.0, through2@2                                                                          .0.3, multipipe@0.1.2, dateformat@1.0.12)
└── lodash@3.10.1

jshint@2.8.0 node_modules/jshint
├── strip-json-comments@1.0.4
├── exit@0.1.2
├── console-browserify@1.1.0 (date-now@0.1.4)
├── minimatch@2.0.10 (brace-expansion@1.1.6)
├── shelljs@0.3.0
├── cli@0.6.6 (glob@3.2.11)
├── htmlparser2@3.8.3 (domelementtype@1.3.0, entities@1.0.0, domhandler@2.3.0, readable-stream@1.1.14, dom                                                                          utils@1.5.1)
└── lodash@3.7.0

geckodriver@1.2.0 node_modules/geckodriver
├── adm-zip@0.4.7
├── bluebird@3.4.6
├── got@5.6.0 (lowercase-keys@1.0.0, timed-out@2.0.0, is-redirect@1.0.0, is-plain-obj@1.1.0, is-stream@1.1                                                                          .0, read-all-stream@3.1.0, object-assign@4.1.0, node-status-codes@1.0.0, duplexer2@0.1.4, unzip-response@1                                                                          .0.2, is-retry-allowed@1.1.0, pinkie-promise@2.0.1, create-error-class@3.0.2, url-parse-lax@1.0.0, readabl                                                                          e-stream@2.2.2, parse-json@2.2.0)
└── tar.gz@1.0.5 (commander@2.9.0, bluebird@2.11.0, tar@2.2.1, fstream@1.0.10, mout@0.11.1)

karma@0.13.22 node_modules/karma
├── isbinaryfile@3.0.1
├── rimraf@2.5.4
├── batch@0.5.3
├── graceful-fs@4.1.11
├── di@0.0.1
├── mime@1.3.4
├── colors@1.1.2
├── source-map@0.5.6
├── http-proxy@1.16.2 (eventemitter3@1.2.0, requires-port@1.0.0)
├── dom-serialize@2.2.1 (void-elements@2.0.1, custom-event@1.0.1, extend@3.0.0, ent@2.2.0)
├── minimatch@3.0.3 (brace-expansion@1.1.6)
├── glob@7.1.1 (path-is-absolute@1.0.1, inherits@2.0.3, fs.realpath@1.0.0, inflight@1.0.6, once@1.4.0)
├── useragent@2.1.9 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── bluebird@2.11.0
├── connect@3.5.0 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.1, debug@2.2.0, finalhandler@0.5.0)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── body-parser@1.15.2 (content-type@1.0.2, bytes@2.4.0, depd@1.1.0, qs@6.2.0, raw-body@2.1.7, on-finished                                                                          @2.3.0, http-errors@1.5.1, iconv-lite@0.4.13, debug@2.2.0, type-is@1.6.14)
├── expand-braces@0.1.2 (array-unique@0.2.1, array-slice@0.2.3, braces@0.1.5)
├── chokidar@1.6.1 (path-is-absolute@1.0.1, async-each@1.0.1, inherits@2.0.3, glob-parent@2.0.0, is-glob@2                                                                          .0.1, is-binary-path@1.0.1, readdirp@2.1.0, anymatch@1.3.0)
├── log4js@0.6.38 (semver@4.3.6, readable-stream@1.0.34)
├── socket.io@1.7.2 (object-assign@4.1.0, socket.io-adapter@0.5.0, has-binary@0.1.7, debug@2.3.3, socket.i                                                                          o-parser@2.3.1, engine.io@1.8.2, socket.io-client@1.7.2)
├── lodash@3.10.1
└── core-js@2.4.1

gulp-jscs@3.0.0 node_modules/gulp-jscs
├── tildify@1.2.0 (os-homedir@1.0.2)
├── through2@2.0.3 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@2.2.2)
├── gulp-util@3.0.7 (array-differ@1.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.3, beeper@1.1.1, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, lodash._r                                                                          eevaluate@3.0.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, m                                                                          inimist@1.2.0, fancy-log@1.2.0, vinyl@0.5.3, chalk@1.1.3, gulplog@1.0.0, lodash.template@3.6.2, multipipe@                                                                          0.1.2, dateformat@1.0.12)
└── jscs@2.11.0 (to-double-quotes@2.0.0, to-single-quotes@2.0.1, estraverse@4.2.0, strip-json-comments@1.0                                                                          .4, reserved-words@0.1.1, natural-compare@1.2.2, vow@0.4.13, pathval@0.1.1, esprima@2.7.3, jscs-preset-wik                                                                          imedia@1.0.0, strip-bom@2.0.0, exit@0.1.2, commander@2.9.0, xmlbuilder@3.1.0, chalk@1.1.3, minimatch@3.0.3                                                                          , glob@5.0.15, cli-table@0.3.1, vow-fs@0.3.6, resolve@1.1.7, jscs-jsdoc@1.3.2, js-yaml@3.4.6, htmlparser2@                                                                          3.8.3, prompt@0.2.14, jsonlint@1.6.2, lodash@3.10.1, escope@3.6.0, babel-jscs@2.0.5)

bower@1.8.0 node_modules/bower

phantomjs@1.9.20 node_modules/phantomjs
├── progress@1.1.8
├── kew@0.7.0
├── which@1.2.12 (isexe@1.1.2)
├── request-progress@2.0.1 (throttleit@1.0.0)
├── hasha@2.2.0 (is-stream@1.1.0, pinkie-promise@2.0.1)
├── extract-zip@1.5.0 (debug@0.7.4, yauzl@2.4.1, mkdirp@0.5.0, concat-stream@1.5.0)
├── fs-extra@0.26.7 (path-is-absolute@1.0.1, jsonfile@2.4.0, klaw@1.3.1, graceful-fs@4.1.11, rimraf@2.5.4)
└── request@2.67.0 (tunnel-agent@0.4.3, aws-sign2@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, oauth-sign@0.8.2, caseless@0                                                                          .11.0, is-typedarray@1.0.0, stringstream@0.0.5, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, t                                                                          ough-cookie@2.2.2, node-uuid@1.4.7, qs@5.2.1, combined-stream@1.0.5, mime-types@2.1.13, bl@1.0.3, hawk@3.1                                                                          .3, http-signature@1.1.1, har-validator@2.0.6, form-data@1.0.1)
./node_modules/.bin/bower install
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more                                                                           about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option
make: *** [requirements.js] Error 1
```

but when i want to migrate it, this happens:

```
sudo make migrate
python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
make: *** [migrate] Error 1
```

Now i'm completely lost. Maybe I am missing something completely essential. I followed this tutorial aswell but it didn't work either: http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/ecommerce/install_ecommerce.html#switch-from-shoppingcart-to-e-commerce

Comment: Coming from someone who has been trying to do this for the last 2 days, there are other problems with this install. Your problem is that you haven't sudo'd into your instance and activated your venv. The next problem you are going to have is during the migration. The original python wasn't compiled correctly before the bitnami venv was created, so the makefile is missing the _sqlite3.so file. When you reconfigure Python, the venv completely breaks. Let me know if you ever figure this one out. Im going to settle w/ the shopping cart and rewrite the preprocessing files

Answer (score 2):

The instructions you are following are for a devstack installation, and, if I remember correctly, Bitnami edX is a native installation of edX in which case you should follow these instructions instead:
https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/110330276/How+to+Install+and+Start+the+E-Commerce+Service+in+Native+Installations

(The fact that you are running your instance on an older version of Ubuntu could, but shouldn't affect you in this installation)